# Need help with install for weil mclain oil boiler

Tags: boiler, tankless

I just bought a weil mclain oil boiler with tankless.

Can anyone tell me the configuration to plumb it?

I asked two heat guys how to plumb it and they gave me different setups.

I plumbed it according to Weil McLain schematic and they said that was wrong.

Comment: You're brave... That's not normally a DIY job. Maybe you didn't actually match the schematic? Having said that, the folks who installed my condensing boiler got it wrong by NOT following the manufacturer's design as written, and I had to have another plumber fix it, so I'd suggest finding someone who's factory-certified if possible.

Comment: What is the model number?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, I generally find that **the manufacturer is a more reliable source of accurate information** than an installer, especially an installer whom you are not using (but then again, you might be wise not to use them, too.) Some installers learned "a particular way" which is either outdated for current equipment or was simply wrong in the first place and depend on that in exclusion to actually reading the instructions; this may not work out well.

The manufacturer has considerably more interest in providing accurate information for successful deployment of their products.